# SensorEventListener in Android : considering a single value

Tags: android

I have the following requirement - When I tilt my phone to the right, Team A get 1 point, when I tilt my phone to the left Team B get 1 point, I use the given code for this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private SensorManager mSensorManager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
}
private final SensorEventListener mSensorListener = new SensorEventListener() {

  public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent se) {
    float x = se.values[0];
    float y = se.values[1];
    float z = se.values[2];
    if((double)Math.round(x * 100000) / 100000>8.00000){
        Log.d("sensor", "=====LEFT====");
    }
    else if((double)Math.round(x * 100000) / 100000 <-8.00000){
        Log.d("sensor", "=====RIGHT====");
    }
  }

  public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
  }
};

@Override
protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  mSensorManager.registerListener(mSensorListener, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
  mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mSensorListener);
  super.onPause();
}

}
```

With this code, when I tilt my phone to the right, "=====RIGHT====" gets printed continuously due to continuous firing of onSensorChanged which is obvious;same is the case is with left. I need to somehow use a method by which I consider only the first onSensorChanged in both the directions and increment the respective score variables for Team A and Team B. This will help me make my calculation correct, such that for a given tilt in one direction, the value gets incremented only once.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a small state machine in there.  In the beginning, you're in the upright state.  If you detect enough of a tilt, you give the correct team 1 point and move to the tilted state.  When you're in the tilted state, no team will get points, but you look for the device to return upright.  If you see that, you move it back to the upright state.  Repeat.

Comment: You suggest to maintain an upright state boolean, such that in the if elseif conditions above,"isUpright" boolean will go to false state. It will become true in another elseif condition for the upright value. Am I correct?